Mechanism of Cu Catalyzed reaction between Benzoic acid with DMF
I'm looking for the mechanism of this reaction that I have stumbled upon. It is believed to be a radical reaction and I can kinda see that but I'm not convinced that I can understand all of the steps, especially the ones including the Cu catalyst.


I've also found the paper from which it appears that this reaction originates and this is their proposed mechanism:

I'm mostly interested in the mechanism of the decarboxylation step and the steps involving the copper catalyst.
